# /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, boot2docker

I am very new to the docker when try to run docker info it gives me following error.

```
$ docker info
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.17/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

I am using ubuntu 14.04.
I followed the installation istructions mentioned on 
https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#installing-docker-on-ubuntu

But I'm still getting the error.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try `$ sudo docker info`?

Comment: it is handy to have 2 aliases `alias docker="sudo docker.io"`
and `complete -F _docker docker` (the last one in order to keep autocompletion)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This error occurred because I didn't restart my computer after installing docker.
Now the above command is working for me.

Comment: Instructions told me to log off, not reboot.  I tried that.  Maybe I should try rebooting.

Comment: Yup, you have to reboot, in spite of what the directions (don't) say, at least on Ubuntu 14.04..

Comment: @NehaG Any ideas on how to fix it on a CI stateless environment were restarting is not an option? (currently using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

Comment: You don't have to reboot... For reasons best known to docker the docker service does not start automatically when installed. As such, In Ubuntu 14.04 `sudo service docker start` did the trick for me

Comment: While restarting might work it's good to check if the daemon is running or not. See my answer for more.

Answer (score 20):

This is because the docker service is not automatically started after an install.

You can start the `docker` service in Ubuntu and its derivatives (looking at you Linux Mint) by typing:

```
sudo service docker start
```

To check that docker started, this file should exist:

```
ls -la /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: I had the same problem when `docker` service was already running. I did `sudo service docker restart` and everything turned fine.

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar issue, restarting didn't work. Running docker -d gave me a different error

```
Error loading docker apparmor profile: exec: "/sbin/apparmor_parser": stat /sbin/apparmor_parser: no such file or directory ()
```

and ran

```
 sudo apt-get install apparmor
```

to fix the apparmor error

My guess the daemon didn't get started automatically post-install because of the apparmor error. (Your error might be different)

Env:  Linux Mint 17.1

Update:
Also make sure the user you are using is in the docker group

Comment: After installing `apparmor`, `docker -d` worked, but `docker info` still show that error.

Comment: Do you see docker running? Run "ps -ef | grep docker" or "cat /var/run/docker.pid"  to find the pid. When I get this error I kill the process and let it respawn a new process.

Comment: Didn't worked at first. Then I tried it with `sudo` and it worked (also Linux Mint). I'm not sure however if doing it with `sudo` is a good practice. Would appreciate if someone more knowledgeable shed some light on this.

Comment: The user should be in docker group if I remember right don't have a docker install right now I can look into.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I needed add my user to docker group (on /etc/group or uses `sudo gpasswd -a user docker` - and restarting the session.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS 3.13.0-57-generic x64

Answer (score 1):

If

```
sudo service docker start
```

isn't working cause you're a different Linux OS (another distro than ubuntu/debian-based): you can use the following command:

```
sudo systemctl status docker
```

If the status says that docker isn't loaded, you can continue the following:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

[or restart (instead of start)]

afterwards `/var/run/docker`

Answer (score 0):

After starting docker. change the owner file with this command:

```
sudo chown [user]:docker /var/run/docker.sock
```

if your problem didn't solve after it.

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
```

then

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/options.conf
```

add this line to options.conf file

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
```