# Docker: Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, daemon, linux-mint

On Linux Mint 17.1 x86_64 with kernel 3.13.0-48-generic and OpenSSL version 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.11; whenever I try to execute any docker command (like `docker login` or `docker run hello-world`), I get the following error:

```
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

I have made a group called `docker` using `sudo usermod -aG docker username`, I have tried running the commands both as root and normally, added `$(boot2docker shellinit 2> /dev/null)` to `~/.profile` as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528337/am-i-trying-to-connect-to-a-tls-enabled-daemon-without-tls), [restarted my PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349112/var-run-docker-sock-no-such-file-or-directory-are-you-trying-to-connect-to-a) and reinstalled OpenSSL.

Any idea what am I missing? Can this be a hardware issue?

Comment: are you using mac os?  boot2docker is for the mac.  it sounds to me like you haven't started the docker daemon.  docker runs in two pieces, the daemon runs in the background. then you connect to the daemon with docker ps, or docker run.  When you connect, you are running docker as a client. so, do a ps -ax | grep docker.  if it isn't there then do a docker -d (or sudo docker -d)

Comment: Yes, now it works. For some reason, `docker -d` doesn't seems to be mentioned in the documentation. By the way, is it safe to run it as `docker -d &` so that I get my shell back?

Comment: Since you're using Mint, look for upstart script for docker server

Comment: Duplicate of [Am I trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528337/am-i-trying-to-connect-to-a-tls-enabled-daemon-without-tls)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can check if it has started by running the command `ps -ef`. You can also grep it to `docker` if you want to reduce the number of results(using `| grep docker`). If its of not running, execute

```
sudo service docker start
```

OR if it still doesn't work then

You can refer this link

[docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/)

You can run `docker run -d` or `docker run -d &` so that you can use the same terminal or even close it if. It will set the value to true, so your container will run in "detached" mode, in the background.

You can also auto start it when your OS starts using `update-rc.d servicename defaults` or you can also refer to the links below, where you have to give `docker` as service name and your defaults.

Some more links to refer - 
[auto start](http://www.howtogeek.com/103640/how-to-make-programs-start-automatically-in-linux-mint-12/),
[upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/)

These are different ways of doing it.

Answer (score 15):

I deployed docker on CentOS 7, and my friend first helped me check whether the process/service `docker` is actually running or not. He used the command `ps -ef | grep docker`. It turned out that the process wasn't running at all. Finally, he started this process by using the command `service docker start`. In the end, the problem was solved.

Comment: That is exactly the point. Seems to not be a "problem" at all. It is just the docker daemon need to be running in order to work

Comment: did you use service docker start or sudo service docker start?

Comment: Or to register it as a service on linux run: #systemctl enable docker.service

Answer (score 9):

Try installing apparmor

```
sudo apt install apparmor
```

There are other things to look for [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29825797/457290) too.

Comment: i did a fresh installation on ubuntu 12.04 (after update the kernel) and i don't know why give this error, i solved installing apparmor

Comment: This answers needs more upvotes. The official Docker install instructions for Ubuntu are missing this step. I've installed Docker now three times into clean Ubuntu systems (once running 12.04 and twice running 14.04). Each time I've spent an hour searching the web, only to stumble back to this SO answer!

Answer (score 9):

I had this same problem when I tried to follow along some online resource; I was able to resolve this by running docker as the super user, try adding `sudo` before your docker commands:

`sudo docker ps -a`

`sudo docker run hello-world`

Hope it helps.

Comment: `sudo docker [command]` solved the problem for me while using Linux.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue when I was creating docker image from Jenkins simply add 
the user to docker group and  then restart docker services and in my case I have to restart Jenkins services

This was the error which I got

```
http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.19/build?cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&memory=0&memswap=0&rm=1&t=59aec062a8dd8b579ee1b61b299e1d9d340a1340: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
FATAL: Failed to build docker image from project Dockerfile
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to build docker image from project Dockerfile


Solution: 

[root@Jenkins ssh]# groupadd docker
[root@Jenkins ssh]# gpasswd -a jenkins docker
Adding user jenkins to group docker
[root@Jenkins ssh]# /etc/init.d/docker restart
Stopping docker:                                           [  OK  ]
Starting docker:                                           [  OK  ]
[root@Jenkins ssh]# /etc/init.d/jenkins restart
Shutting down Jenkins                                      [  OK  ]
Starting Jenkins                                           [  OK  ]
[root@Jenkins ssh]#
```

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same problem this morning. You may just want to do `service docker start`. It works for centos (Could work for all), and its one of those small nagging things i forget all the time.

Technically when you first install a service such as docker or httpd (apache) it needs actually be started otherwise you will get that error. You can also see the status's of other services by doing `service service_name status`but again, that's how it is for my centos 7.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when the docker service is unable to start. 
`sudo service docker start` or `restart` returning no output does not mean that it started successfully.
You can use `sudo /etc/init.d/docker status` to find out if, and why, it failed to start.

In my case, it was due to lack of disk space.

```
username@computer:~$ sudo service docker restart
username@computer:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/docker status
? docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2015-12-21 15:11:59 PST; 21s ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
  Process: 26463 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 26463 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 21 15:11:59 computer docker[26463]: time="2015-12-21T15:11:59-08:00" level=info msg="Listening for HTTP on fd ()"
Dec 21 15:11:59 computer docker[26463]: time="2015-12-21T15:11:59-08:00" level=info msg="+job init_networkdriver()"
Dec 21 15:11:59 computer docker[26463]: time="2015-12-21T15:11:59-08:00" level=info msg="-job init_networkdriver() = OK (0)"
Dec 21 15:11:59 computer docker[26463]: time="2015-12-21T15:11:59-08:00" level=fatal msg="Shutting down daemon due to errors: Insertion failed because database is full: database or disk is full"
Dec 21 15:11:59 computer systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 21 15:11:59 computer systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Dec 21 15:11:59 computer systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Dec 21 15:11:59 computer systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for docker.service
Dec 21 15:11:59 computer systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Dec 21 15:11:59 computer systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

After deleting some files, I was able to restart the service and run docker containers normally.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by running that command in sudo mode, e.g. "sudo docker images"

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem after following the steps at https://docs.docker.com/linux/step_one/. docker service was running and I had also added the user to docker group. docker commands were not working without sudo.

What solved it for me was restarting the PC.
Note- Before PC restart, I had also tried stopping and starting the docker daemon. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Further install and config instructions for Ubuntu can be found at https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/ubuntulinux/.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because of file `/Users/user/.ssh/config` has permissions 777.
To check it run in terminal `ssh docker@localhost`

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem after following the steps at https://docs.docker.com/linux/step_one/. docker service was running and I had also added the user to docker group. docker commands were not working without sudo.

What solved it for me was restarting the PC. Note- Before PC restart, I had also tried stopping and starting the docker daemon. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score -3):

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: chmod 777 give the all rights(read,write,execute) to all processes,its bad practice to use 777 but it does solve the problem as you said @DonaldDuck

Comment: `chmod 777`? Oh no.