# Docker error in Linux mint 17

Tags: docker, linux-mint

I have installed docker in Linux Mint 17 Qiana (which is based on Ubuntu 14.04) present in the Oracle VM. If I tries to start, it shows the following error,

```
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

I couldn't find any useful information regarding this when I tried googling regarding the same. This stackoverflow question suggesting to restart my system, but it doesn't work.

I'm seeing the following related questions which are unhelpful.

[/var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349112/var-run-docker-sock-no-such-file-or-directory-are-you-trying-to-connect-to-a)

[Docker: Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704059/docker-are-you-trying-to-connect-to-a-tls-enabled-daemon-without-tls)

So, any help on this would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Duplicate of [Am I trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528337/am-i-trying-to-connect-to-a-tls-enabled-daemon-without-tls)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I don't know how it comes with `.deb` package (I'm using Fedora), but TLS shouldn't be set by default, so I would suggest following some basic steps to see if it is running correctly.

#### 1. Check if docker daemon is running

```
ps aux | grep docker
root      4215  0.1  0.1 440156 17332 ?        Ssl  15:48   0:00 /usr/bin/docker -d -D --bip=172.17.42.1/16 --dns=172.17.42.1 --dns-search=docker -s overlay
wololock  8986  0.0  0.0 113024  2304 pts/1    S+   15:50   0:00 /usr/bin/grep docker
```

I the docker process is not running, try `sudo /etc/init.d/docker start` or `sudo service docker start`

#### 2. Check if `/var/run/docker.sock` exists

```
ls -la /var/run/docker.*
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   4 04-23 15:48 /var/run/docker.pid
srw-rw----. 1 root docker 0 04-23 15:48 /var/run/docker.sock
```

The important part here is that file need to be own by group `docker`, so you can connect to it without root permissions.

If `docker.sock` does not exist, you can try running docker from the command line with debug mode on to see what causes the problem:

```
sudo docker -d -D
```

#### 3. Check if your user is added to `docker` group

```
id -a
uid=1000(wololock) gid=1000(wololock) grupy=1000(wololock),0(root),10(wheel),100(users),977(docker),989(pkg-build)
```

If you wont find your user in `docker` group, try adding yourself to it by:

```
sudo gpasswd -a [username] docker
```

#### 4. Get the latest docker version

If the previous attempts wont help, try getting the latest docker version from https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#installing-docker-on-ubuntu I'm not sure, but this line:

```
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/containers/json:
```

suggests that you're using docker v1.18. I might be wrong, but if it's true, this is not the most recent docker version and it should be upgraded. I use currently docker v1.5.0, it works well on Fedora 21

## IMPORTANT: UBUNTU / LINUX MINT USERS

The problem we discussed here was caused by missing (or not running) `apparmor` package in the ubuntu/linuxmint distribution. The easiest way to fix it is to install apparmor:

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor
```

If it's installed yet not running, start it with:

```
sudo service apparmor start
```

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor
- https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9745

I hope my answer will help you in resolving your problem. If you have any questions, feel free to ask. I will try to help you as much as I can.

Comment: Hi, % symbol in front of every command throws error. Is that the one you intended to type?

Comment: No no, my bad. It's my prompt symbol. I will remove it so it does not confuse anyone. :)

Comment: The second one shows, "ls: cannot access /var/run/docker.*: No such file or directory". Should i create?

Comment: It says, that your docker daemon is not running correctly. Try `sudo docker -d -D` to run is as a daemon (-d option) with debug mode enabled (-D option). It should say what is the problem, we can continue from that point.

Comment: `sudo docker -d -D` returns with the error `FATA[0000] Shutting down daemon due to errors: Error loading docker apparmor profile: fork/exec /sbin/apparmor_parser: no such file or directory ()` at the end.

Comment: Check this one - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29796836/2194470 Sid had similar problem with apparmor, in his case installing/starting the apparmor daemon helped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76073/discussion-between-udhayakumar-and-szymon-stepniak).