# "Is your docker daemon up and running?" Problems with docker hello world tutorial on Linux

Tags: linux, docker

I am running the installation tutorial for [Docker](http://docs.docker.com/linux/step_one/) on Linux - Ubuntu 14.04

Going step by step through the tutorial, I get the following error message:

```
docker run hello-world

Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.20/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory.
* Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
* Is your docker daemon up and running?
```

The similar question [docker error: /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372781/docker-error-var-run-docker-sock-no-such-file-or-directory) refers to `boot2docker` which I am not using

Comment: @Woot4Moo there is no Docker file -- this is the Hello World tutorial

Comment: There most assuredly is one.  Or you have a magic tutorial

Comment: This isn't related to a `Dockerfile`. He can't even talk to the daemon yet so anything done to a `Dockerfile` won't help.

Comment: Check this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349112/var-run-docker-sock-no-such-file-or-directory-are-you-trying-to-connect-to-a/29796836#29796836

Comment: What version of Linux are you running 32 or 64 bit? Can you also post the output from the `env` command

Answer (score 29):

Had the same issue, solved:

```
docker-machine start default
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

Comment: When I run this commend, I get: 
`Error: Host does not exist: default`
Did anyone else encounter this issue?

Comment: You've to start the Docker application. Goto Applications and click on Docker (as of now, there is no way to start from terminal). Once the startup is complete, you'll see docker icon in Mac's taskbar.

Answer (score 11):

I got the same problem today. you just have to start the service.

`sudo service docker start`

It works on linux. I don't know if it works on mac

Comment: it works on linux. I don't know if you have service on mac sorry

Comment: Works on centos 7.1. Thanks

Comment: @mskw  mac is `docker-machine start default`, as @E-Xor said

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem running docker on ubuntu 14.04.

Trying running Docker as root:
`sudo docker run hello-world`

Type in password when prompted.

Answer (score 3):

Check the ownership of the file `/var/run/docker.sock`:

```
ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw----. 1 root root 0 Nov 18 16:17 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Change the group settings to `dockerroot`:

```
sudo chown root:dockerroot /var/run/docker.sock

ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw----. 1 root dockerroot 0 Nov 18 16:17 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

***Both the solution here are tried and tested on linux only***
**Solution 1:**
I was Having the same issue, Login with root privilege solved my problem
[image]
**Solution 2:**
The solution here works only with root user because root user has full access to linux socket similarly docker group has full access to linux socket. 
if you want to run this with non root user you need to add user to docker group, you can do this with following command -

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)
```

Now **logout and login** you should be able to work with non-root user :)

Answer (score 0):

After getting stuck I turned off the computer and went on a road trip.  One Monday I turned the computer on and `docker run hello-world` runs just as the tutorial indicated.

Comment: Because Docker was not running. It was installed (along with the init script) and when you rebooted the computer the init script was run. The initial error pointed this out as the very first thing...

Comment: This is my first time using docker and really it is only because it is required to install another library called [splash](https://splash.readthedocs.org/en/latest/kernel.html)

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same problem on Windows 8.1
Answer was to open the Oracle VM Virtual Box, right click on the default instance and then click on "Show" icon. Then saw BootLocker logo. 
Then back to the Docker Quickstarter "> whale" icon, double click and ascii docker appears.

Answer (score 0):

In linux, after installation, though `docker version` was giving a proper output, `docker run hello-world` was not working because the service was not up.

I tried `service docker restart` in SLES 12 SP3 Linux machine. It worked. So probably your docker daemon needs a restart.

Try the same command `service docker restart` and it should work.

Answer (score -2):

So, is the Docker daemon running? What troubleshooting did you already do?

The tutorial doesn't mention starting Docker or adding yourself to the `docker` group so that you can run Docker command without `sudo` (although, this should have been mentioned when you installed Docker). You need to do both of these things first.

Comment: If the docker daemon were running or not, I wouldn't know.   No troubleshooting as I expected Docker to work out of the box.

Comment: You can find out using `/etc/init.d/docker status`

Comment: My point was that the message you got back, quite literally, asked if the daemon was running and you seemingly chose to ignore that. The very first Google search result for the message brings you to https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15620 which explains the problem and how to resolve it.